# Uncaught ReferenceError data is not defined

Tags: reactjs, api, mapping

I'm trying to fetch an API into a state and using the map method to give a new array.

But it gives this error `Uncaught ReferenceError data is not defined`

Here's the code-

```
const [games,setGAMES] = React.useState([])
const [gamesList,setGamesList] = React.useState([])
  React.useEffect(()=>{
    const options = {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'X-RapidAPI-Key': '68cd3db2f1mshf35a2b8ae04ad85p1fc5a1jsn0f05ed6a893a',
        'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'free-to-play-games-database.p.rapidapi.com'
      }
    };
    fetch('https://free-to-play-games-database.p.rapidapi.com/api/filter?tag=3d.mmorpg.fantasy.pvp&platform=pc', options)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then( data => {setGAMES(data)})
      setGamesList( data.map( (object) => {
        return {
          name: object.title,
          link: object.game_url,
        }
      }))
    },[])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setGamesList` function is being called out of the .then, this is causing the `not defined` error.

Moved the function inside the block, this should work.

```
React.useEffect(()=>{
    const options = {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'X-RapidAPI-Key': '68cd3db2f1mshf35a2b8ae04ad85p1fc5a1jsn0f05ed6a893a',
        'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'free-to-play-games-database.p.rapidapi.com'
      }
    };
    fetch('https://free-to-play-games-database.p.rapidapi.com/api/filter?tag=3d.mmorpg.fantasy.pvp&platform=pc', options)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then( data => {
        setGAMES(data);
        setGamesList( data.map( (object) => {
          return {
            name: object.title,
            link: object.game_url,
          }
        }))
      })
    },[])
```